# How do you set a background image in a frame with pygtk?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk

I mean like a frame with some widgets which overlap the background (the image), basically how do you partially overlap/clobber an Image?

Like a background in a Firefox theme, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is a [FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq08.021.htp).